# html5 video error on Windows phone

Tags: html, video, windows-phone-8, html5-video

I'm trying to integrate video for mobile phones with HTML5. On iphone, OK, on Android it's slow but OK, and for windows phone, I have a bad error: invalid source .
This is the code that don't work for Windows Phone:

```
<div align="center">
         <video autobuffer height="170" width="300" controls>
            <source src="http://dev.com/cloud.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="http://dev.com/cloud.webm" type="video/webm">
            <source src="http://dev.com/cloud.ogv" type="video/ogg">
         </video>
    </div>
```

I tried the code of W3Schools on the mobiles and it work on Windows Phone (This is the .mp4 that runs on WP) :

```
<div align="center">
         <video width="320" height="240" controls="">
            <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
        </video>
    </div>
```

What is my mistake? If it is encodage, how Can I transform it and wich codec, ... HOW :-)

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have the mp4 version of the movie you want to show? and is it properly encoded?

Comment: Thanks for your adk @scunliffe Yes, all the videos are on the server and it is encoded as mp4. I'm not the person who encoded but It must be welle encoded.. There is a way to test them?

Comment: try pointing to a completely different mp4 file generated by someone else... if that works, your file is not correct/correctly encoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The video was well encoded. the problem was there was a wrong MIME typeon the server configuration. The MIME was .mp4 => "application/octet-stream", but here the WP doesn't understand this MIME, so I edit it to "video/mp4", and it works.

Comment: which configuration?

Comment: On the IIS configuration window