# html video tag on WindowsPhone "Invalid Source" - working from URL but not from relative path

Tags: html, windows-phone-8.1, html5-video

My app is a cordova/phonegap app.
I am including a **video** tag on my windows phone 8.1.

It strangely works from URL

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">        
 Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

while it does not work from relative path

```
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
       <source src="img/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">        
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
```

**movie.mp4** is included in the folder img of my project.

Message displayed is "**Invalid Source**";

Why does it happen?
The video is exactly the same.

PS: it works loading from IE 11 and Chrome.

Same video is working also when I use it in a c# windows-phone app and play it via XAML element, this way:

```
    <MediaElement x:Name="mediaSimple" 
          Source="Assets/video/movie.mp4" 
          Width="400" AutoPlay="True"/>
```

Comment: What server are you using? Or is it loading from a local file?

Comment: @aldel, it is loading from local

Comment: Did you check for the Mime-Type that is returned in the _Content-Type_ header from the server? Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546519/html5-video-error-on-windows-phone